# How to count elements of the same class until other class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I count the number of `cv_item` until next `cat_header_holder`

My attempt is below, however this merely outputs 0 for each `cat_header_holder`

Example HTML:

```
<div class="cat_holder">

<div class="cat_header_holder">
 <h1>Header <span class="cv_cat_count"></span></h1></div>

<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>
<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>

<div class="cat_header_holder">
 <h1>Header <span class="cv_cat_count"></span></h1></div>

<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>
<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>
<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>
<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>

<div class="cat_header_holder">
 <h1>Header <span class="cv_cat_count"></span></h1></div>

<div class="cv_group"> <a class="cv_item" href></a> </div>


</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.cat_header_holder').each(function () {
    var count = $(this)
                  .closest(".cv_group")
                  .nextUntil("div:has(.cat_header_holder)")
                  .find(".cv_item")
                  .length;

     $(".cv_cat_count").text(count);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```js
 $('.cat_header_holder').each(function() {
   var count = $(this).nextUntil('.cat_header_holder').find(".cv_item").length;
   $(this).find(".cv_cat_count").text(count);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat_holder">
  <div class="cat_header_holder">
    <h1>Header <span class="cv_cat_count"></span></h1></div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cat_header_holder">
    <h1>Header <span class="cv_cat_count"></span></h1></div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
  <div class="cat_header_holder">
    <h1>Header <span class="cv_cat_count"></span></h1></div>
  <div class="cv_group">
    <a class="cv_item" href></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You were adding `.closest` which traverses up the DOM.

Comment: That name "closest" seems to confuse most jQuery newbies. They assume it traverses in all directions (or whatever direction they happen to care about at the time).